# Changes in scss files not reflect in css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I want changes in my .scss files automatically reflect into css files.

I'm using Rails 3.

I places sass files to publish/stylesheets/sass folder

I've added:

```
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
```

to config.ru

However changes in scss styles still not reflect into css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that I was wrong and all works correct even without running:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compress
```

The problem was connected with fact, that empty styles declared in scss are not reflected to css.

For example:

```
.myclass {
}
```

When I have added some properties inside it everything stark working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you or something's changed with rails 3, you need to have sass running in terminal:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compress
```

Comment: Thanks mark, but I find out that with Rails 3 it is not necessary.